# Form validation issue with Ajax without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have two forms on my page and I'm hiding one `myForm` on submission to show other `otherForm` using ajax.

For that, I need to execute the function `submit_form();` onclick. As this is being submitted without refreshing the page with jQuery and Ajax, if the fields are empty, the the form `myForm` will be hidden without sending the data.

How can I prevent the form from hidding or validate it's fields before being submitted?

This is my form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
 Name:    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
 Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
<input class="newsletter" type="button" id="submitForm" value="Send" onclick="submit_form();"/>
```

This is the `submit_form` function:

```
function submit_form() {
    var values = {};
    $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
    $('#myForm').hide();
    $('#otherForm').show();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $.post("submit.php", { name: name, email: email, },
    function(data) {
     $('#results').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: just check if its empty then skip ajax ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the object value present or not using `Array#filter` length

```js
function submit_form() {
  var values = {};
  $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
    values[field.name] = field.value.trim();
  });

  if(Object.values(values).filter(a => !a).length > 0 ){
   return false
  }
  console.log(values)
  $('#myForm').hide();
  $('#otherForm').show();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();

  $.post("submit.php", {
      name: name,
      email: email,
    },
    function(data) {
      $('#results').html(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br /> Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
  <input class="newsletter" type="button" id="submitForm" value="Send" onclick="submit_form();" />
```